# Allow top level scopes to access ui-view child scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application structured as follows:

```
application
  * header
    * ui-view specific menu item
    * ui-view specific menu item
    * ui-view specific menu item
  * sidebar
    * link with ui-sref
    * link with ui-sref
  * content
    * ui-view
```

How can a header menu item access the scope of the `ui-view`?

For example when the `Contacts` view is active the `header` contains two links, `New Contact` and `Export Contacts`:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="header">
    <a ng-click="onNewContactClicked()">New Contact</a>
    <a ng-click="onExportContactsClicked()">Export Contacts</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <a ui-sref="Calendar()">
    <a ui-sref="Contacts()" class="active">
  </div>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

The `Contacts` view has a controller `ContactsCtrl`. So to rephrase my question, how can the menu item `New Contact` access and call the function `onNewContactClicked` defined in `ContactsCtrl`?

Sometimes the `ui-view`s can be nested. For example the `Contacts` view can have a `Edit Contact` view. That nested view should also be accessible by the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't communicating navigation through your routes (which I would recommend) you can use events instead. The header controller might look something like this and use the root scope to broadcast messages based on navigation:

```
app.controller("headerController", ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    var _this = this;
    $scope.onNewContactClicked = function() {
        _this.$rootScope.$broadcast("newContact");
    };
    $scope.onExportContactsClicked = function() {
        _this.$rootScope.$broadcast("exportContacts");
    };
}]);
```

Then you can pick up the messages in your other controllers like this:

```
app.controller("contactsController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    var _this = this;
    $scope.$on("newContact", function() {
        _this.$scope.message = "Do new contact stuff.";
    });
    $scope.$on("exportContacts", function() {
        _this.$scope.message = "Do export stuff.";
    });
}]);
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/BPX49/

The nice thing about broadcast is that it will be sent to all scopes no matter what level they are nested at, so you can have your edit controller pick up messages as well. Just add a second parameter to send information along as a payload.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want! I thought broadcasts propagated down, from child to parent, but that doesn't make any sense because child scopes inherit from the parent scope. Another small question: is it possible to make a menu item disabled from within the `ContactsCtrl`? Something like this `<a ng-click="onExportContactsClicked()" ng-disabled="contactsCtrl.exportButton.disabled">Export Contacts</a>`?

Comment: $broadcast goes to child scopes, and $emit goes to parent scopes. Easiest way to condition the button is to set a container at the root level, i.e. $rootScope.permissions = {} then you can do permissions.exportButton.disabled in the header controller and set $scope.permissions.exportButton.disabled in the contacts controller (it will inherit from the root)